# Filter array on unnamed column in PowerAutomate

Tags: arrays, filter, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am creating a workflow in PowerAutomate. I have some content that I turn into an array by splitting at [TEXTTOSPLITAT]. The "split text" happens at the beginning of the content so while I get all the rows I want, the first row is "". A freshly split string is broken into unnamed columns so how would I then use the filter array action and filter on [content in row] is not "" to shave off the blank first row?

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution I provided below helps your problem ?

Comment: Any update ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, you have two options:

**First solution:** Remove the first `split text` before you do the split. For example, I have a string content named `var1` and its value is `,11,22,33`. I want to split it to array with `,` symbol so I initialize another variable named `var2` with the expression `substring(variables('var1'), 1, sub(length(variables('var1')),1))` as its value. The expression is to remove the first `,`. After that, use `split(variables('var2'), ',')` to split `var2` to array (shown as below screenshot).
[image]

**Second solution:** As I don't know details of your split operation and your content, so if it's not convenient for you to remove the first `split text` before do split operation, you can choose this solution. Do same thing as you mentioned in question and when you want to use "**Filter**" action, use `skip(variables('<the array name>'), 1)` as the input content of the "**Filter**" action (shown as below screenshot).
[image]